# 'Li' element showing as `undefined`

Tags: javascript, html

Started to do a todo list on my own to practice JS

When I add the text/task to the todo, HTML text showing-

> Undefined

Made sure getElementbyId etc was right but unsure if missing something. Design is rubbish, just want to try JS out.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
        <title>To doist</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class= "main-title-bar">
        <h1>To doist</h1>
      </div>
      <div id = "button">
        <button>+</button>
      </div>
      <div class = "input" id = "input">
        <input type="text" class="add_tast" placeholder="Task">
        <span onclick="newElement()" onkeypress="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
      </div>
      <div class = "todo-list">
          <ul id="myUL">

         </ul>
      </div>
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
//Click button to get input field

let button = document.getElementById('button')

button.addEventListener("click",showInput)

function showInput(event){
    if(event.type === "click"){
    input.classList.toggle("show")
}
}
const input = document.querySelector(".input")

// Create new element for the classList

function newElement(){
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  let inputValue = document.getElementById("input").value;
  let t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === ''){
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("input").value = "";
  console.log('Is it working?');
}
```

Expecting to see the name of my task on HTML as for example "Going to the gym"

Comment: `#input` is a `div`, it has no `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed your code. `document.getElementById("input").value;`

`input` tag is not id it's tag.

if you want get value from input tag must using through id use to this code.
  `document.getElementById("id").value;`

```js
let button = document.getElementById('button')

button.addEventListener("click",showInput)

function showInput(event){
    if(event.type === "click"){
        input.classList.toggle("show")
    }
}
const input = document.querySelector(".input")

// Create new element for the ClassList

function newElement(){
debugger;
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  let inputValue = $("#tasks").val();
  let t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === ""){
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("input").value = "";
  console.log('Is it working?');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
        <title>To doist</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class= "main-title-bar">
        <h1>To doist</h1>
      </div>
      <div id = "button">
        <button>+</button>
      </div>
      <div class = "input" id = "input">
        <input type="text" id="tasks" class="add_tast" placeholder="Task">
        <span onclick="newElement()" onkeypress="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
      </div>
      <div class = "todo-list">
          <ul id="myUL">

         </ul>
      </div>
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have given the `id="input"` to the div instead of the input element. Give the id to the input an it will work

```js
let button = document.getElementById('button')

button.addEventListener("click",showInput)

function showInput(event){
    if(event.type === "click"){
    input.classList.toggle("show")
}
}
const input = document.querySelector(".input")

function newElement(){
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  let inputValue = document.getElementById("input").value;
  let t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === ''){
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("input").value = "";
  console.log('Is it working?');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
        <title>To doist</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class= "main-title-bar">
        <h1>To doist</h1>
      </div>
      <div id = "button">
        <button>+</button>
      </div>
      <div class = "input" >
        <input type="text" id = "input" class="add_tast" placeholder="Task">
        <span onclick="newElement()" onkeypress="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
      </div>
      <div class = "todo-list">
          <ul id="myUL">

         </ul>
      </div>
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```